# Android Retrofit on Kotlin how i can add timestamp to response?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, response

I have a simple Json class that handles retrofit perfectly.
But there is no timestamp in it.
I add my custom field which is not in json, but it is always null

```
//Custom field for timestamp
val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())


//My class for JSON respons 
@Entity(tableName = "nal")
data class CurrencyItem(

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id:Long,

@SerializedName("base_ccy")
var baseCcy: String,
@SerializedName("buy")
val buy: String,
@SerializedName("ccy")
val ccy: String,
@SerializedName("sale")
val sale: String,

val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
)
```

Comment: @Transient for timestamp?

Comment: I get exchange rates in json but the time is not written in them, I need to add time to the response model class in order to know the latest update time

Comment: a) custom deserializer or b) drop data class and use regular class, and put timestamp initialization in the init block

Comment: Thanks! Deserializer looks good, but I can't find a normal example for kotlin retrofit2, java only.

Comment: I see you already posted a question on custom deserializer, so you are working on that, cool, won't then expand on that here, except to say that a custom deserializer is actually the way to go here  (so my option b above is wrong) - init block won't be  run by retrofit so changing to regular class won't help. But there is also another option - assign all default values to each parameter, and then your timestamp will work. Its ugly and unlikely you will want it, but just pointing out another option

Comment: Thanks for response.  Just can’t understand why such a complex architecture and everything is so incomprehensible in android, why I just can’t read JSON into an array and add timestamp(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution add custom field in model for timestamp.

```
val timeStamp: String
```

Аnd when retrofit response come, rewrite this null field with timestamp, i use method SimpleDateFormat

```
// retrofit response
var res  = resp.body()

// new list which i create and rewrite with timestamp and then return
var l = ArrayList<CurrencyItem>()

//read response list with json converted data
for (r in res.orEmpty()){
   l.add(CurrencyItem(1 ,
                    r.baseCcy,
                    r.buy,
                    r.ccy,
                    r.sale,
                    SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())))
 }

 //return this new list with timestamp. I use repository pattern with livedata
 response.value = l
```